# Excel Search and copy

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I have a column of value's (i.e. J9264, J9000, etc...) I need to search a series of 100-200 values from worksheet 1 (column A) and pair them to worksheet 2 (column A). Once I identify those 100 values (out of series of 10,000 values) I need to find the corresponding value in the next column (column b) to those numbers. Once I determine all of those values I need to bring them back to worksheet 1 (column B).

Ex. J9264 has a corresponding value of $100 in Worksheet 2. I need the value of $100 to be copied over to Worksheet 1. I need to do this for all 100 values that I am searching for.

Comment: What have you tried? If you show us the code that you tried and the error message that you are getting then it will be easy for us to help you :)

Comment: Your question is a little confusing, but it sounds like a VLookup or some variant might be a simple solution?

Answer (score 0):

As @ARich has mentioned, VLOOKUP seems a simple solution, so for the sake of an answer and though I do not have a Macintosh and this does not apply VBA, I suggest:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,'worksheet 2'!A:B,2,0),"")
```

in B2 (assuming columns are labelled) of worksheet 1 and copied down to suit.